# Why are Outlook 2007 categories not being sent back on email replies?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

I set a category for a mail message before I send it. When the person replies, that category is no longer assigned to the mail message.

In Outlook 2003, doing the same thing would have the category still set on the reply message.

I'm in a corporate Exchange server world, is there something that needs to be enabled on the server or maybe my client? I liked this feature in 2003, but after migrating to 2007, the feature is gone.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Outlook 2007 includes a default client-only rule called "Clear categories on mail" which is applied to inbound mail.  If your recipients are also running Outlook 2007, they will never see your outbound categories after their Outlook filters them on the inbound side.

EDIT: There are two rules in my installation, one for client-only (.pst) and one labeled without the "client-only" tag, presumably for IMAPI accounts.

EDIT2: To take a look for yourself, `Tools | Rules and Alerts...`

Comment: Well, well, look at that! I have unchecked it and will now see what happens. Thanks for the response

Comment: Unchecking it on your side will only affect your receipt of messages that have categories assigned to them.  Every one of your recipients will need to make that same change if you want them all to receive your categories.

Comment: I do not like how Microsoft implemented this feature in 2007. I "loose" my categories now because the recipients have that rule set. When the message leaves their desk, the categories are removed -- grrr.